# Cannot find URL error while it is definitely there

Tags: html, linux, url, cgi

I have small CGI script running on a server[Linux OS]. following is a part of script output..

```
<tr><td valign="center">Lol</td><td valign="center">10112</td><td><a 
href="/home/pathtopdf/abc.pdf">abc.pdf</a></td></tr>
```

But when I click on this abc.pdf hyperlink, browser displays error message:`URL /home/pathtopdf/abc.pdf was not found on the server.` while the pdf and path is definitely there and all files and folders in the path[including pdf] has full permission.

My server location is @ `/srv/www` and script in `/srv/www/cgi-bin`, but when I put the link to pdf as follows

```
<tr><td valign="center">Lol</td><td valign="center">10112</td><td><a 
href="/srv/www/for_html/abc.pdf">abc.pdf</a></td></tr>
```

The error message was `The requested URL '/srv/www/for_html/abc.pdf' resolves to a file which is marked executable but is not a CGI file; retrieving it is forbidden.` Again permission is there for files.

What could be the problemo?

Comment: The URL is not in the webserver root folder.

Comment: Do you have a webserver configured to serve files from your entire file system?

Comment: You think it's there and it's really not? Something tells me that `/home` is not actually a directory for your website. Remember that `/` goes to your root **web** directory, not to the root of your system.

Comment: @animuson the second part is backwards. :/

Comment: The funny thing is the same script had run successfully by displaying pdfs on clicking hyperlink. So you saying server configuration might have changed in between?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: No, it's not. In the context of a website, `/` always goes to the root web directory defined by the server config.

Comment: @animuson whoops. didn't realize you were referring to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to request a file outside of the webroot. So by clicking that, the browser is really requesting

```
http://example.com/home/pathtopdf/abc.pdf
```

not

```
/home/pathtopdf/abc.pdf
```

You can edit your apache config file and add a virtual host to that directory under a subdomain (say downloads)

Answer (score 0):

After your edit, I am assuming you are using the `file://` protocol, directly on the server. I would say just to remove the executable bit from your `.pdf`'s file permissions.  Run from a shell:

```
chmod -x /srv/www/for_html/abc.pdf
```

Comment: That solved the problem when files are under /srv/www/ and not when say under /home/.....

Comment: @spyke There is probably another permissions issue for files under home. Your web server needs to be able to read whatever file you want to download from it. If you are not concerned with other users reading your file you could do the same procedure as above except replacing `-x` with `+r` to make sure the web server (and any other user) can read it.